# Reactjs Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a cloned reacjs project from github but I'm unable to run it beacuse I get the error below.

`Uncaught runtime errors: ERROR Maximum call stack size exceeded RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at Object.hasOwnProperty (<anonymous>) at Le (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:94756:9) at Le (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:94756:271)`

I have looked into it and realised that the problem is from a specific file. whenever I import the file, (even just the import alone) into any component it throws this error above.

import { components } from "ComponentRenderer.js";

The code below is the content of the file "ComponentRenderer.js".

I don't seem to see what could possibly be throwing the error. How can I fix this error

```
import AnimationRevealPage from "helpers/AnimationRevealPage.js";
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

import AgencyLandingPage from "demos/AgencyLandingPage.js";
import EventLandingPage from "demos/EventLandingPage.js";
import HostingCloudLandingPage from "demos/HostingCloudLandingPage.js";
import HotelTravelLandingPage from "demos/HotelTravelLandingPage.js";
import RestaurantLandingPage from "demos/RestaurantLandingPage.js";
import SaaSProductLandingPage from "demos/SaaSProductLandingPage.js";
import ServiceLandingPage from "demos/ServiceLandingPage.js";

import AgencyLandingPageImageSrc from "images/demo/AgencyLandingPage.jpeg";
import EventLandingPageImageSrc from "images/demo/EventLandingPage.jpeg";
import HostingCloudLandingPageImageSrc from "images/demo/HostingCloudLandingPage.jpeg";
import HotelTravelLandingPageImageSrc from "images/demo/HotelTravelLandingPage.jpeg";
import RestaurantLandingPageImageSrc from "images/demo/RestaurantLandingPage.jpeg";
import SaaSProductLandingPageImageSrc from "images/demo/SaaSProductLandingPage.jpeg";
import ServiceLandingPageImageSrc from "images/demo/ServiceLandingPage.jpeg";


import AboutUsPage from "pages/AboutUs.js";
import BlogIndexPage from "pages/BlogIndex.js";
import ContactUsPage from "pages/ContactUs.js";
import LoginPage from "pages/Login.js";
import PricingPage from "pages/Pricing.js";
import PrivacyPolicyPage from "pages/PrivacyPolicy.js";
import SignupPage from "pages/Signup.js";
import TermsOfServicePage from "pages/TermsOfService.js";

import AboutUsPageImageSrc from "images/demo/AboutUsPage.jpeg";
import BlogIndexPageImageSrc from "images/demo/BlogIndexPage.jpeg";
import ContactUsPageImageSrc from "images/demo/ContactUsPage.jpeg";
import LoginPageImageSrc from "images/demo/LoginPage.jpeg";
import PricingPageImageSrc from "images/demo/PricingPage.jpeg";
import PrivacyPolicyPageImageSrc from "images/demo/PrivacyPolicyPage.jpeg";
import SignupPageImageSrc from "images/demo/SignupPage.jpeg";
import TermsOfServicePageImageSrc from "images/demo/TermsOfServicePage.jpeg";

import BackgroundAsImageHero from "components/hero/BackgroundAsImage.js";
import BackgroundAsImageWithCenteredContentHero from "components/hero/BackgroundAsImageWithCenteredContent.js";
import FullWidthWithImageHero from "components/hero/FullWidthWithImage.js";
import FeaturesAndTestimonialHero from "components/hero/TwoColumnWithFeaturesAndTestimonial.js";
import IllustrationAndInputHero from "components/hero/TwoColumnWithInput.js";
import IllustrationAndPrimaryBackgroundHero from "components/hero/TwoColumnWithPrimaryBackground.js";
import IllustrationAndVideoHero from "components/hero/TwoColumnWithVideo.js";

import ThreePlansPricing from "components/pricing/ThreePlans.js";
import ThreePlansWithHalfPrimaryBackgroundPricing from "components/pricing/ThreePlansWithHalfPrimaryBackground.js";
import TwoPlansWithDurationSwitcherPricing from "components/pricing/TwoPlansWithDurationSwitcher.js";

import ThreeColumnDashedBorderFeatures from "components/features/DashedBorderSixFeatures";
import ThreeColCenteredStatsWithPrimaryBackgroundFeatures from "components/features/ThreeColCenteredStatsPrimaryBackground.js";
import ThreeColSimpleFeatures from "components/features/ThreeColSimple.js";
import ThreeColWithSideImageFeatures from "components/features/ThreeColWithSideImage.js";
import ThreeColWithSideImageWithPrimaryBackgroundFeatures from "components/features/ThreeColWithSideImageWithPrimaryBackground.js";
import WithStatsAndImageFeatures from "components/features/TwoColSingleFeatureWithStats.js";
import WithStatsAndImage2Features from "components/features/TwoColSingleFeatureWithStats2.js";
import TwoColWithButtonFeatures from "components/features/TwoColWithButton.js";
import WithStepsAndImageFeatures from "components/features/TwoColWithSteps.js";
import TwoColVerticalWithButtonFeatures from "components/features/TwoColWithTwoFeaturesAndButtons.js";
import TwoColHorizontalWithButtonFeatures from "components/features/TwoColWithTwoHorizontalFeaturesAndButton.js";
import VerticalWithAlternateImageAndTextFeatures from "components/features/VerticalWithAlternateImageAndText.js";

import PortfolioCards from "components/cards/PortfolioTwoCardsWithImage.js";
import ProfileThreeColGridCards from "components/cards/ProfileThreeColGrid.js";
import TabGridCards from "components/cards/TabCardGrid.js";
import ThreeColContactDetailsCards from "components/cards/ThreeColContactDetails.js";
import SliderCards from "components/cards/ThreeColSlider.js";
import TrendingCards from "components/cards/TwoTrendingPreviewCardsWithImage.js";

import GridWithFeaturedPostBlog from "components/blogs/GridWithFeaturedPost.js";
import PopularAndRecentPostsBlog from "components/blogs/PopularAndRecentBlogPosts.js";
import ThreeColSimpleWithImageBlog from "components/blogs/ThreeColSimpleWithImage.js";
import ThreeColSimpleWithImageAndDashedBorderBlog from "components/blogs/ThreeColSimpleWithImageAndDashedBorder.js";

import SimplePrimaryBackgroundTestimonial from "components/testimonials/SimplePrimaryBackground.js";
import ThreeColumnWithProfileImageTestimonial from "components/testimonials/ThreeColumnWithProfileImage.js";
import TwoColumnWithImageTestimonial from "components/testimonials/TwoColumnWithImage.js";
import TwoColumnWithImageAndProfilePictureReviewTestimonial from "components/testimonials/TwoColumnWithImageAndProfilePictureReview.js";
import TwoColumnWithImageAndRatingTestimonial from "components/testimonials/TwoColumnWithImageAndRating.js";

import SimpleWithSideImageFAQS from "components/faqs/SimpleWithSideImage.js";
import SingleColFAQS from "components/faqs/SingleCol.js";
import TwoColumnPrimaryBackgroundFAQS from "components/faqs/TwoColumnPrimaryBackground.js";

import SimpleContactUsForm from "components/forms/SimpleContactUs.js";
import SimpleSubscribeNewsletterForm from "components/forms/SimpleSubscribeNewsletter.js";
import TwoColContactUsForm from "components/forms/TwoColContactUsWithIllustration.js";
import TwoColContactUsFullForm from "components/forms/TwoColContactUsWithIllustrationFullForm.js";

import DownloadAppCTA from "components/cta/DownloadApp.js";
import GetStartedCTA from "components/cta/GetStarted.js";
import GetStartedLightCTA from "components/cta/GetStartedLight.js";

import FiveColumnDarkFooter from "components/footers/FiveColumnDark.js";
import FiveColumnWithBackgroundFooter from "components/footers/FiveColumnWithBackground.js";
import FiveColumnWithInputFormFooter from "components/footers/FiveColumnWithInputForm.js";
import MiniCenteredFooter from "components/footers/MiniCenteredFooter.js";
import SimpleFiveColumnFooter from "components/footers/SimpleFiveColumn.js";


export const components = {
  landingPages: {
    RestaurantLandingPage: {
      component: RestaurantLandingPage,
      imageSrc: RestaurantLandingPageImageSrc,
      url: "/components/landingPages/RestaurantLandingPage",
    },
    HotelTravelLandingPage: {
      component: HotelTravelLandingPage,
      imageSrc: HotelTravelLandingPageImageSrc,
      url: "/components/landingPages/HotelTravelLandingPage",
    },
    SaaSProductLandingPage: {
      component: SaaSProductLandingPage,
      imageSrc: SaaSProductLandingPageImageSrc,
      url: "/components/landingPages/SaaSProductLandingPage",
    },
    ServiceLandingPage: {
      component: ServiceLandingPage,
      imageSrc: ServiceLandingPageImageSrc,
      url: "/components/landingPages/ServiceLandingPage",
    },
    EventLandingPage: {
      component: EventLandingPage,
      imageSrc: EventLandingPageImageSrc,
      url: "/components/landingPages/EventLandingPage",
    },
    AgencyLandingPage: {
      component: AgencyLandingPage,
      imageSrc: AgencyLandingPageImageSrc,
      url: "/components/landingPages/AgencyLandingPage",
    },
    HostingCloudLandingPage: {
      component: HostingCloudLandingPage,
      imageSrc: HostingCloudLandingPageImageSrc,
      url: "/components/landingPages/HostingCloudLandingPage",
    },
  },

  innerPages: {
    LoginPage: {
      component: LoginPage,
      imageSrc: LoginPageImageSrc,
      scrollAnimationDisabled: true,
      url: "/components/innerPages/LoginPage",
    },
    SignupPage: {
      component: SignupPage,
      url: `/components/innerPages/SignupPage`,
      imageSrc: SignupPageImageSrc,
      scrollAnimationDisabled: true,
    },
    PricingPage: {
      component: PricingPage,
      url: `/components/innerPages/PricingPage`,
      imageSrc: PricingPageImageSrc,
    },
    AboutUsPage: {
      component: AboutUsPage,
      url: `/components/innerPages/AboutUsPage`,
      imageSrc: AboutUsPageImageSrc,
    },
    ContactUsPage: {
      component: ContactUsPage,
      url: `/components/innerPages/ContactUsPage`,
      imageSrc: ContactUsPageImageSrc,
    },
    BlogIndexPage: {
      component: BlogIndexPage,
      url: `/components/innerPages/BlogIndexPage`,
      imageSrc: BlogIndexPageImageSrc,
    },
    TermsOfServicePage: {
      component: TermsOfServicePage,
      url: `/components/innerPages/TermsOfServicePage`,
      imageSrc: TermsOfServicePageImageSrc,
    },
    PrivacyPolicyPage: {
      component: PrivacyPolicyPage,
      url: `/components/innerPages/PrivacyPolicyPage`,
      imageSrc: PrivacyPolicyPageImageSrc,
    }
  },

  blocks: {
    Hero: {
      type: "Hero Section",
      elements: {
        BackgroundAsImage: {
          name: "With Background Image",
          component: BackgroundAsImageHero,
          url: "/components/blocks/Hero/BackgroundAsImage",
        },
        IllustrationAndInput: {
          name: "With Image Illustration and Input",
          component: IllustrationAndInputHero,
          url: "/components/blocks/Hero/IllustrationAndInput",
        },
        IllustrationAndVideo: {
          name: "With Image Illustration and Video",
          component: IllustrationAndVideoHero,
          url: "/components/blocks/Hero/IllustrationAndVideo",
        },
        FeaturesAndTestimonial: {
          name: "With Features And Customer Testimonial",
          component: FeaturesAndTestimonialHero,
          url: "/components/blocks/Hero/FeaturesAndTestimonial",
        },
        FullWidthWithImage: {
          name: "Full Width With Image",
          component: FullWidthWithImageHero,
          url: "/components/blocks/Hero/FullWidthWithImage",
        },
        BackgroundAsImageWithCenteredContent: {
          name: "Full Width Background Image with centered content",
          component: BackgroundAsImageWithCenteredContentHero,
          url: "/components/blocks/Hero/BackgroundAsImageWithCenteredContent",
        },
        IllustrationAndPrimaryBackground: {
          name: "Primary Background With Illustration",
          component: IllustrationAndPrimaryBackgroundHero,
          url: "/components/blocks/Hero/IllustrationAndPrimaryBackground",
        },
      }
    },
    Pricing: {
      type: "Pricing Section",
      elements: {
        TwoPlansWithDurationSwitcher: {
          name: "Two Plans With Duration Switcher",
          component: TwoPlansWithDurationSwitcherPricing,
          url: "/components/blocks/Pricing/TwoPlansWithDurationSwitcher",
        },
        ThreePlansWithHalfPrimaryBackground: {
          name: "Three Plans With Primary Background at Top",
          component: ThreePlansWithHalfPrimaryBackgroundPricing,
          url: "/components/blocks/Pricing/ThreePlansWithHalfPrimaryBackground",
        },
        ThreePlans: {
          name: "Simple Three Plans",
          component: ThreePlansPricing,
          url: "/components/blocks/Pricing/ThreePlans",
        },
      }
    },
    Features: {
      type: "Features Section",
      elements: {
        ThreeColWithSideImage: {
          name: "Three Column With Side Image",
          component: ThreeColWithSideImageFeatures,
          url: "/components/blocks/Features/ThreeColWithSideImage",
        },
        TwoColWithButton: {
          name: "Two Column With Image and Action Button",
          component: TwoColWithButtonFeatures,
          url: "/components/blocks/Features/TwoColWithButton",
        },
        ThreeColSimple: {
          name: "Three Column Simple",
          component: ThreeColSimpleFeatures,
          url: "/components/blocks/Features/ThreeColSimple",
        },
        ThreeColWithSideImageWithPrimaryBackground: {
          name: "Three Column With Side Image With Primary Background",
          component: ThreeColWithSideImageWithPrimaryBackgroundFeatures,
          url: "/components/blocks/Features/ThreeColWithSideImageWithPrimaryBackground",
        },
        TwoColHorizontalWithButton: {
          name: "Two Column With Button and Horizonatal Features with Icon",
          component: TwoColHorizontalWithButtonFeatures,
          url: "/components/blocks/Features/TwoColHorizontalWithButton",
        },
        TwoColVerticalWithButton: {
          name: "Two Column With Vertical Features and Button",
          component: TwoColVerticalWithButtonFeatures,
          url: "/components/blocks/Features/TwoColVerticalWithButton",
        },
        WithStepsAndImage: {
          name: "Steps with Image",
          component: WithStepsAndImageFeatures,
          url: "/components/blocks/Features/WithStepsAndImage",
        },
        ThreeColumnDashedBorder: {
          name: "Three Column With Dashed Primary Border",
          component: ThreeColumnDashedBorderFeatures,
          url: "/components/blocks/Features/ThreeColumnDashedBorder",
        },
        ThreeColCenteredStatsPrimaryBackground: {
          name: "Three Column With Centered Stats on Primary Background",
          component: ThreeColCenteredStatsWithPrimaryBackgroundFeatures,
          url: "/components/blocks/Features/ThreeColCenteredStatsPrimaryBackground",
        },
        WithStatsAndImage: {
          name: "Stats With Image",
          component: WithStatsAndImageFeatures,
          url: "/components/blocks/Features/WithStatsAndImage",
        },
        WithStatsAndImage2: {
          name: "Stats With Image 2",
          component: WithStatsAndImage2Features,
          url: "/components/blocks/Features/WithStatsAndImage2",
        },
        VerticalWithAlternateImageAndText: {
          name: "Vertical Feature Cards With Alternate Image and Text",
          component: VerticalWithAlternateImageAndTextFeatures,
          url: "/components/blocks/Features/VerticalWithAlternateImageAndText",
        },
      }
    },

    Cards: {
      type: "Cards",
      elements: {
        Slider: {
          name: "Three Column Slider",
          component: SliderCards,
          url: "/components/blocks/Cards/Slider",
        },
        Portfolio: {
          name: "Two Column Portfolio Cards With Images ",
          component: PortfolioCards,
          url: "/components/blocks/Cards/Portfolio",
        },
        TabGrid: {
          name: "Tab Card Grid With Tab Switcher",
          component: TabGridCards,
          url: "/components/blocks/Cards/TabGrid",
        },
        ProfileThreeColGrid: {
          name: "Three Column Grid Cards For Profile",
          component: ProfileThreeColGridCards,
          url: "/components/blocks/Cards/ProfileThreeColGrid",
        },
        ThreeColContactDetails: {
          name: "Three Column Contact Details Cards",
          component: ThreeColContactDetailsCards,
          url: "/components/blocks/Cards/ThreeColContactDetails",
        },
        Trending: {
          name: "Two Trending Preview Cards With Images",
          component: TrendingCards,
          url: "/components/blocks/Cards/Trending",
        },
      }
    },

    Blog: {
      type: "Blog Section",
      elements: {
        GridWithFeaturedPost: {
          name: "Grid With Featured Post",
          component: GridWithFeaturedPostBlog,
          url: "/components/blocks/Blog/GridWithFeaturedPost",
        },
        PopularAndRecentPosts: {
          name: "Popular And Recent Posts",
          component: PopularAndRecentPostsBlog,
          url: "/components/blocks/Blog/PopularAndRecentPosts",
        },
        ThreeColSimpleWithImage: {
          name: "Simple Three Column With Image",
          component: ThreeColSimpleWithImageBlog,
          url: "/components/blocks/Blog/ThreeColSimpleWithImage",
        },
        ThreeColSimpleWithImageAndDashedBorder: {
          name: "Simple Three Column With Image and Dashed Border",
          component: ThreeColSimpleWithImageAndDashedBorderBlog,
          url: "/components/blocks/Blog/ThreeColSimpleWithImageAndDashedBorder",
        },
      }
    },

    Testimonial: {
      type: "Testimonial Section",
      elements: {
        TwoColumnWithImage: {
          name: "Two Column With Image",
          component: TwoColumnWithImageTestimonial,
          url: "/components/blocks/Testimonial/TwoColumnWithImage",
        },
        TwoColumnWithImageAndProfilePictureReview: {
          name: "Two Column With Image And Profile Picture Review",
          component: TwoColumnWithImageAndProfilePictureReviewTestimonial,
          url: "/components/blocks/Testimonial/TwoColumnWithImageAndProfilePictureReview",
        },
        TwoColumnWithImageAndRating: {
          name: "Two Column With Image And Rating",
          component: TwoColumnWithImageAndRatingTestimonial,
          url: "/components/blocks/Testimonial/TwoColumnWithImageAndRating",
        },
        ThreeColumnWithProfileImage: {
          name: "Three Column With Profile Image",
          component: ThreeColumnWithProfileImageTestimonial,
          url: "/components/blocks/Testimonial/ThreeColumnWithProfileImage",
        },
        SimplePrimaryBackground: {
          name: "Simple With Primary Background",
          component: SimplePrimaryBackgroundTestimonial,
          url: "/components/blocks/Testimonial/SimplePrimaryBackground",
        },
      }
    },

    FAQS: {
      type: "FAQs Section",
      elements: {
        SimpleWithSideImage: {
          name: "Simple With Side Image",
          component: SimpleWithSideImageFAQS,
          url: "/components/blocks/FAQS/SimpleWithSideImage",
        },
        SingleCol: {
          name: "Single Column",
          component: SingleColFAQS,
          url: "/components/blocks/FAQS/SingleCol",
        },
        TwoColumnPrimaryBackground: {
          name: "Two Column With Primary Background",
          component: TwoColumnPrimaryBackgroundFAQS,
          url: "/components/blocks/FAQS/TwoColumnPrimaryBackground",
        },
      }
    },

    Form: {
      type: "Forms Section",
      elements: {
        SimpleContactUs: {
          name: "Simple Contact Us",
          component: SimpleContactUsForm,
          url: "/components/blocks/Form/SimpleContactUs",
        },
        SimpleSubscribeNewsletter: {
          name: "Simple Subscribe newsletter",
          component: SimpleSubscribeNewsletterForm,
          url: "/components/blocks/Form/SimpleSubscribeNewsletter",
        },
        TwoColContactUs: {
          name: "Two Column Contact Us",
          component: TwoColContactUsForm,
          url: "/components/blocks/Form/TwoColContactUs",
        },
        TwoColContactUsFull: {
          name: "Two Column Contact Us - Full Form",
          component: TwoColContactUsFullForm,
          url: "/components/blocks/Form/TwoColContactUsFull",
        },
      }
    },

    CTA: {
      type: "CTA Section",
      elements: {
        GetStarted: {
          name: "Get Started",
          component: GetStartedCTA,
          url: "/components/blocks/CTA/GetStarted",
        },
        GetStartedLight: {
          name: "Get Started Light",
          component: GetStartedLightCTA,
          url: "/components/blocks/CTA/GetStartedLight",
        },
        DownloadApp: {
          name: "Download App",
          component: DownloadAppCTA,
          url: "/components/blocks/CTA/DownloadApp",
        },
      }
    },

    Footer: {
      type: "Footers Section",
      elements: {
        SimpleFiveColumn: {
          name: "Simple Five Column",
          component: SimpleFiveColumnFooter,
          url: "/components/blocks/Footer/SimpleFiveColumn",
        },
        FiveColumnWithInputForm: {
          name: "Five Column With Input Form",
          component: FiveColumnWithInputFormFooter,
          url: "/components/blocks/Footer/FiveColumnWithInputForm",
        },
        FiveColumnWithBackground: {
          name: "Five Column With background",
          component: FiveColumnWithBackgroundFooter,
          url: "/components/blocks/Footer/FiveColumnWithBackground",
        },
        FiveColumnDark: {
          name: "Five Column Dark",
          component: FiveColumnDarkFooter,
          url: "/components/blocks/Footer/FiveColumnDark",
        },
        MiniCentered: {
          name: "Mini Centered Dark",
          component: MiniCenteredFooter,
          url: "/components/blocks/Footer/MiniCentered",
        },
      }
    }
  }
}

export default function ComponentRenderer() {
  const { type, subtype, name } = useParams()

  try {
    let Component = null;
    if (type === "blocks" && subtype) {
      Component = components[type][subtype]["elements"][name].component
      return <AnimationRevealPage disabled>
        <Component />
      </AnimationRevealPage>
    }
    else
      Component = components[type][name].component

    if (Component)
      return <Component />

    throw new Error("Component Not Found")
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
    return <div>Error: Component Not Found</div>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error suggest the memory goes out of range, that simply means your code somewhere goes in loop and accumulate lots of data and dont free it.
So look where there is a circular dependency, a imports b, b imports c and c imports a again, which is very possible because of a lots of components.

To Debug, you can continue removing batch of component import and narrow down your error source and you can use [react developer tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi) to debug.